# How to ignore the first zeros in the result of a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to ignore if there are any zero values in the first days of production.

```
SELECT D_DATE, PRODUCE FROM PRODUCTION
```

**Dataset**

```
Date         Produce
1/1/2015        0
1/2/2015        0
1/3/2015        0
1/4/2015        6
1/5/2015        5
1/6/2015        2
1/7/2015        0
1/8/2015        1
1/9/2015        1
```

The first three days are zeros which I would like to ignore in my result but the 7th day should not be ignored

**Desired Result**

```
Date         Produce
1/4/2015        6
1/5/2015        5
1/6/2015        2
1/7/2015        0
1/8/2015        1
1/9/2015        1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity I assume that there is at least one day with produce > 0.

```
SELECT d_date, produce
FROM production
WHERE
    d_date >= (
        SELECT MIN(d_date)
        FROM production
        WHERE
            produce != 0
    )
;
```

Comment: This does not work, I am still getting 0 values on the dataset.

Comment: @szakwani For the 7th day? You said earlier "it should not to be ignored". Explain your sample data and expected results.

Comment: I meant I am still getting initial 0 values on the dataset.

Comment: @szakwani Don't know how you do this. Provide sqlfiddle to check. Here is mine - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6d069/2

Comment: Working as expected, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUM as analytical function to calculate the cumulative sum of produce and filter those greater than zero.

```
select d_date, produce
from (
        select 
        d_date, 
        produce, 
        sum(produce) over (order by d_date) cuml_produce
        from production
)
where cuml_produce > 0
order by d_date;
```

Comment: Why are you taking the cumulative? It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT date,
       produce
FROM
(
SELECT date,
       produce,
       row_number() over (order by date) r1,
       row_number() over (order by produce, date) r2
FROM  production
) A
WHERE r1 != r2
```

Comment: results are not as expected at all. Resulted in duplicates, and every record was zero.

Comment: I tested this on the data you have provided and its working perfectly. On what data you have tested and where its failing.

Comment: Could you share your fiddle?

Answer (score -1):

Use correlated subquery.

```
SELECT Date, Produce, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATE) RN 
INTO #Temp
FROM tbl

SELECT t.Date, t.Produce  FROM #Temp t
WHERE 
 EXISTS(
                 SELECT 1 FROM #Temp t1 
                  WHERE t1.rn < t.rn
                  AND t1.PRODUCE !=0)
OR T.Produce != 0
```

[Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/939c9b/1)

Comment: @szakwani -  Updated my answert with a fiddle

Comment: its in SQLSERVER, Im using oracle friend

Comment: Yes, I know. For some reason, I am not able to create table script  on fiddle for Oracle. Hence I did using MS-SQL Server. When you run this in your environment, is it throwing any error?

Comment: In oracle you can not use # as table names

Comment: My create table script does not have a #.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73327/discussion-between-sourav-agasti-and-szakwani).

Answer (score -2):

Assuming your date is in DATETIME, will this help you?

```
SELECT D_DATE, PRODUCE
FROM PRODUCTION
where  Date  >= (select TOP 1 Date from PRODUCTION where PRODUCE > 0 Order by DATE)
```

Comment: As specified in the tag it's an oracle database.

Comment: EATABLE ANSWER IS:

SELECT d_date, produce
FROM production
WHERE
    d_date >= (
      select MIN(d_date) from PRODUCTION 
      where PRODUCE > 0       
    );